# C++11 - emplacing a variable to any std container (vector, list, set, unordered_set)

Tags: c++11, decltype, emplace

Trying to write a generic code to emplace a default constructed object into an std container and return an iterator to it.

with insert the solution is

```
template<typename C>
typename C::iterator insert(C& container)
{
    return container.insert(container.end(), typename C::value_type());
}
```

But emplace has no such common interface so I had to specialize it for 2 container types.
My best attempt (that did not compile) was:

```
template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace_back())
{
    return container.emplace_back();
}

template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace().first)
{
    return container.emplace().first;
}
```

This causes: `error: void value not ignored as it ought to be`

and I don't understand why my decltype was deduced as void.

Used gcc 4.8.5 with -std=c++11

Edit:

reproduced by

int main()
{
        std::vector v;
        std::vector::iterator iv = emplace(v);

```
    std::set<int> s;
    std::set<int>::iterator is = emplace(s);
    return 0;
```

}

Edit 2:

second attempt

```
template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace().first)
{
    return container.emplace().first;
}

template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace(container.end()))
{
    return container.emplace(container.end());
}
```

works for verctor, but set is ambiguous.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What containers did you test with, and with which compiler?

Comment: vector, list, set, unordered_set. gcc 4.8.5 with -std=c++11

Comment: error reproduced with: `int main()
{
        std::vector<int> v;
        std::vector<int>::iterator i = emplace(v);
        return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it thanks to @Quentin:

```
// For vector, list and anything push_backable
template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace_back(),container.rbegin())
{
    container.emplace_back();
    return container.rbegin();
}

// For set,unordered_set, and anything that emplace returns a pair.
template<typename C>
auto emplace(C& container)
    -> decltype(container.emplace().first)
{
    return container.emplace().first;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, it took me longer than it should've.

[`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) only returns the emplaced object since C++17. Before then, it returns `void`, and even in C++17 the return type is a reference, not an iterator.

It looks like your specialization for `emplace_back()` should be modified to return `container.back()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Changed to `container.emplace(container.end())`

Comment: But now the emplace for set is ambiguous.

Comment: Posted a fix. Thanks for your help!